# MONGO DB QUERY : How to query for getting projected values from lookup pipeline as key pair in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to query for getting projected values from lookup pipeline as key pair in mongoose

```
{
$lookup:{
  from:'response',
  localField:'_id',
  foreignField:'user',
  as:'dataResponse'
  pipeline:[{project:{ resId:1,status:1}]
}



email : "test@test.com"
dataRespose : [ 
{_id: '63515eea05c8c884a33b291d', resId: '632f2d8e470895396dccefdb', status: 'IN_PROGRESS'} ,
{_id: '6385ee9f451fa8879071bcde', resId: '63771adafa3b611596aaa15d', status: 'CREATED'}`]
```

how to get like this

```
email : "test@test.com"
dataRespose : {
632f2d8e470895396dccefdb : 'IN_PROGRESS' ,
63771adafa3b611596aaa15d : 'CREATED'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can create an object using values for the field names is by using [the `$arrayToObject` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/). In the example below, we use that operator inside of a subsequent `$addFields` stage and `$map` over the `dataResponse` array that is returned by the preceding `$lookup`. During that processing we generate the object document with the `k` and `v` fields (needed for `$arrayToObject` set to the values from the fields that you are interested in (`resId` and `status`):

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dataResponse": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$dataResponse",
            "in": {
              k: "$$this.resId",
              v: "$$this.status"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "dataResponse": {
      "632f2d8e470895396dccefdb": "IN_PROGRESS",
      "63771adafa3b611596aaa15d": "CREATED"
    },
    "email": "test@test.com"
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A9COiYV8e_P).

You could do something similar inside of the `pipeline` embedded in the `$lookup` if you desired, but functionally the results will be the same.